# Linear Algebra (Matrixes with powers)

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let
$$
M \colon= \left[ \begin{matrix} 
2 & -1 \\
2 & 5
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

Find formulas for the entries of $M^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

$$ M^n = \text{?} $$

Comment: Try diagonalization.

Comment: Don't diagonalize. Compute the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$ of $M$. Then $p(M)=0$. If you divide $x^n$ by $p(x)$ then for the remainder $r(x)$ you will have $M^n=r(M)$. Since the remainder is of degree at most $1$, you can compute its coefficients by interpolating $s_i^n=r(s_i)$ for the eigenvalues of $M$, $s_1$ and $s_2$.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $(x-3)(x-4)$. Therefore $r(3)=3^n$ and $r(4)=4^n$. Therefore, $r(x)=3^n\frac{x-4}{3-4}+4^n\frac{x-3}{4-3}$. This tells you that $M^n=\frac{3^n}{3-4}(M-4I)+\frac{4^n}{4-3}(M-3I)$

Comment: @egorovik Those comments should really be an answer instead.

Comment: @amd They are answers.

Comment: @egorovik No, they’re not. They’re comments. Answers belong down below.

Comment: @amd For all I see they are answers. Go ahead and copy them if you want to see them somewhere else.

Comment: @egorovik If you’re going to participate in this SE, you really ought to follow its rules. As it says in the tour, “Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer.” If you’re going to answer the question, then post an answer so that it can be accepted and the question not left hanging.

Comment: @amd I clarified the question and the comment above mine. Take it easy, there are things that you can't control. Do what is in your hands. You want to see what I wrote down there. You can write it down there. Making me? That's out of your hands.

Answer (score 1):

I think simple diagonilization makes sense here for  $M$ has two different eigenvalues, $\{3,4\}$. Two corresponding eigenvectors are $[1,-1]^\top$ and $[1,-2]^\top$. Setting
\begin{align}
P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
-1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
can be expressed $M$ as $M= P\Delta P^{-1}$ where $\Delta=\operatorname{diag}(3,4)$, that is
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & -1\\
2 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1\\
-1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 0\\
0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1\\
-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Thus
\begin{align}
M^n = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1\\
-1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
3^n & 0\\
0 & 4^n
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1\\
-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
2\cdot3^n - 4^n & 3^n - 4^n\\
2(4^n-3^n) & -3^n - 2\cdot4^n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

This is of course the same as what was mentioned in one of the comments above (egorovik)

Answer (score -1):

Look for the Eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

$$\det(M-\lambda I)=0$$

Then the eigenvectors:

$$M\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$$

Put the eigenvectors as columns in a $2\times 2$ matrix $P$, and compute $P^{\textrm{T}}MP$. Note that $P^{\textrm{T}}P=PP^{\textrm{T}}=I$

Comment: For the property $P^TP=PP^T=I$ one would need the eigenvectors to be orthogonal with respect to the scalar product $(x,y)=y^Tx$. This is not always the case. It happens, for example, when $M$ is symmetric.

Comment: Odd that this was exactly the same comment as Oliver Diaz...

Comment: In their answer they factor $M$ in the form $PDP^{-1}$, using an invertible matrix $P$ and its inverse, as opposed to a factorization of the form $PDP^T$ or $P^TDP$, with an invertible, but also orthogonal matrix $P$. The latter is a stronger requirement. Diagonalization in the first sense is not available always. In the second sense even less. For the particular matrix $M$ in this question diagonalization in your sense is doesn't exist. If it were some other matrix maybe diagonalization in their sense wouldn't exist either. One of the reasons why diagonalization is not the best approach.

Comment: Another reason for not diagonalizing is that it requires more computation than necessary. Yet another reason is that, if done with a computer, is more numerically unstable.